# Grails not generating all SQL tables in many-to-many

Tags: mysql, grails

I'm a new to Grails and have started a project, but I'm having troubles finding out what is wrong:

The project is already connected to my database (SQL) and it has a few many-to-many to relationship with more than 1 "parameter", like this:

```
static hasMany = [rules:AvaliateRules,professors:Professor,candidates:Candidate];
```

I run the application with no problems, but when I used show tables  the transaction tables weren't all created. It just created the last parameter's table (candidate).

Any idea about the reason and how to fix it? everywhere I checked, people did the same as me and had no problems with the tables. I'm using grails 2.4.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your current domain has many-to-many relationship with all  entities that you mentioned. It might be a one-to-many relationship. Let's say your current domain is "DomainA". If only other domain like AvaliateRules,Professor has "DomainA" in hasMany then it makes it a many-to-many association.

In one-to-many association, only a column is added at the child level(many side) which contains a parentId to denote who the parent is.

Comment: some of them were many-to-many but they were not being created. I still don't know what was wrong but I continued the project, changed a couple things and the tables ended up being created. thanks though.